# Array: could not find array type for data type character varying[]

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have the following sample data for demo:

**Table**:

```
create table tbl_array
(
   array_data varchar[]
);
```

Some values:

```
insert into tbl_array values('{AUS,USA}'),('{IND,SA}'),('{UK,UAE,NZ}'),('{CAN,BAN,SL,KW}');
```

**Query**: I have input values `{USA,AUS}` or `{KW,CAN,SL,BAN}` or `{UK,UAE,NZ}` to get details from tbl_array. Input values can come with any sequence.

**Expected Output**:

For `{USA,AUS}`:

```
array_data
-------------
{AUS,USA}
```

For `{KW,CAN,SL,BAN}`:

```
array_data
-------------
{CAN,BAN,SL,KW}
```

For `{UK,UAE,NZ}`:

```
array_data
-------------
{UK,UAE,NZ}
```

**Try**:

```
select *
from tbl_array where array_data = ALL('{USA,AUS}');
```

Getting an error:

> could not find array type for data type character varying[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl_array where array_data @> '{USA,AUS}' AND array_length(array_data, 1) = 2;
```

It must contain both (ignores order) and be of length 2 (to exclude other cases if you wish).

`array_length(array_data, 1)` the 1 means your array is one dimensional.

I also assume you have **no duplicates** in your arrays.

Also note that array contains `@>` can benefit from GIN indexes.